# net Core 2.0 precompile views in library project fails with strange error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a library that is loaded  by a web app at runtime.  The library dll and views are copied to a special Modules folder, in the web app, at compile time.  The web app locates and registers the library OK and the views work as expected.  I used parts of  a number of sites to set this up, mainly [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1109475/Modular-Web-Application-with-ASP-NET-Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1109475/Modular-Web-Application-with-ASP-NET-Core%20this%20one) amongst others.

When deploying to Azure the issue is that the various views under the Modules folder are being precompiled which fails as the main web app knows nothing of the various classes and services that the view needs.  Note, the web app does not reference the library project.

One quick solution was to turn off view compilation for the whole project which did allow the web app to be deployed but suffers from speed issues as the views are no longer compiled.

OK, I then thought to precompile the views in the library and deploy that along with the web app.

This is where the trouble starts.  Much googling later I discover that this is not simple and the csproj needs to be manually modified by inserting the following:

```
  <Target Name="SetMVCRazorOutputPath">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MvcRazorOutputPath>$(OutputPath)</MvcRazorOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="_MvcRazorPrecompileOnBuild" DependsOnTargets="SetMvcRazorOutputPath;MvcRazorPrecompile" AfterTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' " />
  <Target Name="IncludePrecompiledViewsInPublishOutput" DependsOnTargets="_MvcRazorPrecompileOnBuild" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish" Condition=" '$(IsCrossTargetingBuild)' != 'true' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_PrecompiledViewsOutput Include="$(MvcRazorOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).PrecompiledViews.DLL" />
      <_PrecompiledViewsOutput Include="$(MvcRazorOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectName).PrecompiledViews.pdb" />
      <ContentWithTargetPath Include="@(_PrecompiledViewsOutput->'%(FullPath)')" RelativePath="%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Identity)" TargetPath="%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Filename)%(_PrecompiledViewsOutput.Extension)" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Sort of makes sense except that I get an error when building the library project where the precompiling fails.  The error is:

```
Error   MSB3073 The command ""dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig "C:\Code\MyProject\LibraryProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\LibraryProject.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "C:\Code\MyProject\LibraryProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\LibraryProject.deps.json" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll" @"obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code -2147450733.
```

Not much help in the error code sadly.

This is generated and look OK to me:

microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp:

```
C:\CodeMyProject\LibraryProject
--output-path=bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\
--application-name=LibraryProject
--content-root=C:\CodeMyProject\LibraryProject
--file=C:\CodeMyProject\LibraryProject\Views\UnitPeriodImporter\Index.cshtml
--file=C:\Code\MyProject\LibraryProject\Views\UnitPeriodImporter\_CreateImportBatch.cshtml
--file=C:\CodeMyProject\LibraryProject\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml
```

Any ideas?  I would very much like to turn on precompiling again.

Please note the file and project names have been adjusted for security reasons.

Gordon

Comment: I'm struggling with that too. I found out that the window "web publish activity" shows more information about what is going on. In my case, the first one was missing a file (runtimeconfig.json). Now there is another one. Maybe this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the "LibraryProject.runtimeconfig.json" and "LibraryProject.deps.json" files are missing.

Try adding the following in your csproj.

```
<Target Name="AddRuntimeConfigFileToBuiltProjectOutputGroupOutput" Condition="'$(GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles)' == 'true' And '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'" BeforeTargets="BuiltProjectOutputGroup">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuiltProjectOutputGroupOutput Include="$(ProjectRuntimeConfigFilePath)" FinalOutputPath="$(ProjectRuntimeConfigFilePath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```